# "Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path"

Tags: java, opencv, jenkins

I have a selenium test that when it finishes makes some operations with OpenCV. With IntelliJ IDEA it works fine, the operations process correctly, but when I try to execute through command line (for Jenkins use in the near future), I get the error mentioned above:

"Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path"

I read the other questions on here and I've set up the java.library.path to the path where the jar and dll files are, but the error still comes up and I'm running out of ideas.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you `set up the java.library.path to the path where the jar and dll files are`? How have you checked that this setting is active when the selenium test runs? How does your command look for `execute through command line`?

Comment: Like this -> -Djava.library.path="/path/to/OpenCV/library"
Then I printed it through the execution and the path desired was printed so I guess that worked OK. The command I execute for selenium is this: mvn test -Denv=FIREFOX

Comment: Have you `printed it through the execution` when you run your test with `mvn test -Denv=FIREFOX` or only when you run it manually? Beeing a bit more detailed in what you did would help others to give a valid answer. Digging in the dust isn't really a good approach.

Comment: Sorry @SubOptimal, should have been a bit more detailed. I had done it manually, but now I did it with the command line "mvn test -Denv=FIREFOX" and I can see that it is not pointing to the desired path. I was able to add it but it is still not working. This is what I did to add it: `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Users\\a578675\\Documents\\t21_omnia_automation\\.idea\\libraries");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java320")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find below a working snippet. Which you need to adapt to your needs.

**assume following file structure**

```
libs\opencv_java320.dll
pom.xml
src\test\java\sub\optimal\OpenCVTest.java
```

**pom.xml** - the part for the testing

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${project.basedir}/libs/</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**sub\optimal\OpenCVTest.java**

```
package sub.optimal;
import org.junit.Test;
public class OpenCVTest {
    @Test
    public void someOpenCVTest() {
        System.out.printf("java.library.path: %s%n",
                System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java320");
    }    
}
```

**run the test**

```
mvn compile test
```

**output**

```
...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running sub.optimal.OpenCVTest
java.library.path: X:\develop\opencv-demo/libs/
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: ...
...
```

Comment: for sbt users on MacOS, `sbt -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.5/share/OpenCV/java/ "runMain behavioural.FaceRecognitionService"`, also https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html is helpful

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. I am using intellij on mac

```
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    //System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); - REMOVE THIS
    nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(); //add this
    Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    System.out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());
 }
}
```

And dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
   <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0-0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me without any intellij settings

Comment: that doesn't work with org.openpnp:opencv:4.3.0-1`, in case of this updated dependency nu.pattern.OpenCV can't be fount

Answer (score 2):

If you are using STS/Eclipse or any IDE then follow the steps to getting solve your **unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-opencv-java320** error.

Window -> Preferences -> User Libraries -> New -> create new Library Like attached Image

**Note**:- Jar location and Native Library Location (opencv/build/java/x64) should be exactly like this while creating the new library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA you should add OpenCV library as Native Library Location.

1. Go to `File` > `Project Structure`
2. From side panel select `Modules` and then select the `Dependencies` tab
3. Click the `+` icon on the bottom to add a dependency. Then select the `Add JARS or directories` option.
4. Then browse to the path where you installed the OpenCV and select `build/bin/opencv-***.jar` (or build/java/opencv-***.jar in some case) and click `Open`.

   ※ If you can not find that jar file. I predict that you forgot build OpenCV repo. Reference this [introduction](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)
5. It will be shown as dependency in the window. Now, we also have to add the Native Library Location. To do that, double click on the opencv-***.jar
6. Then click on the `+` icon to add the Native Library Location.
7. And then browse to the location where you installed OpenCV and select `build/lib`(in somecase it will be `build/java/x64`). Now click `Open`.

[image]

Now, you can use `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` to load library as expected

Reference: [How to set-up OpenCV in IntelliJ IDEA](https://medium.com/@aadimator/how-to-set-up-opencv-in-intellij-idea-6eb103c1d45c) of Aadam

PS: You also can add `java.library.path` in VM option like `-Djava.library.path={PATH_T0_LIBRARY}`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This working for me on intellij Idea :

1. Open your project in intellij Idea,
2. Go to File->ProjectStructure->Libraries then click + (Java)
3. Then add the .dll file. In my case I had: \opencvFolder\build\java\x64\opencv_java320.dll
4. Now go to File->Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies then click + (Jars or directories)
5. Then add the opencv jar file. In my case I had: \opencvFolder\build\java\opencv-java320

And it worked ! Hope this will help :)