# Is there a way to set up dependency for javacv's native part in maven, without manual installation and setting up java.library.path?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I have dependencies on `org.bytedeco:opencv:4.1.2-1.5.2` that is in turn added to the project by

```
        <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
        <artifactId>datavec-data-image</artifactId>
        <version>${datavec.version}</version>
```

And for the needs of `datavec-data-image` the open-cv is loaded well and all the internal open-cv actions are executed.

Then, I'd like to do some open cv executions explicitly. I use a class from https://github.com/rostrovsky/pdf-table that does this stuff:

```
public class PdfTableReader {

    private TableExtractor extractor;
    private PdfTableSettings settings;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
```

and it fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java412 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at pdftable.PdfTableReader.<clinit>(PdfTableReader.java:32)
    at pdftable.ExtractSyzlekFromPdf.main(ExtractSyzlekFromPdf.java:12)
```

What I should to do to make this explicit `javacv` part to work with `datavec` image code without doing the double explicit `open-cv` installation to some location on my pc and setting up the `java.library.path` explicitly? At least the `datavec` image code obtains it somehow without this explicit set up.

I also tried to follow up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515132/1759063 but with no success (if I understand right, they use the dependency that ships native libs in a cross-platform way, i.e. ships all platform binaries and the needed one is used on the right platform). I suppose there should be a way to make `java.library.path` to be dynamically updated if the `open-cv` native binaries packed to the maven dependencies are attached to the project. But how?

If DL4J guys can explain how to use the javacv part there correctly, that would be perfect.

Comment: Have you called `Loader.load(opencv_java.class)`? https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv#documentation

Comment: @SamuelAudet no, I used `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` What it a full class name for the `Loader` and from what library/dependency it is?

Comment: @SamuelAudet sorry, missed the link you have atached, got it, let me check

Comment: @SamuelAudet yes, that helped. Please post your comment as the official answer. This line wasn't explicily called in DL4J code, maybe because it is called somewhere under the hood. And using double call of this `Loader.load(opencv_java.class)` exactly at places of `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)` double call caused the exception like this: `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy  at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java API of OpenCV found in the `org.opencv` package doesn't come with a loader, so the libraries need to be loaded by something else externally. In the case of the JavaCPP Presets for OpenCV, the libraries and wrappers are all bundled in JAR files and we can call `Loader.load(opencv_java.class)` to load everything as documented here:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv#documentation

JavaCV, Deeplearning4j, and DataVec do not use that Java API of OpenCV, they use the API found in the `org.bytedeco.opencv` package, which loads everything automatically, so they do not need to call anything.